# Python - Update dictionary int values by adding from another dictionary Counter()

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

```
origincount = {
        'Bug': 0,
        'Important': 0,
        'User Story': 0,
        'Critical': 0,
        'Moderate': 0,
        'Low': 0,
        'story': 0
    }
    if epic['archived'] is False:
        for story in stories:
            if story['epic'] is not None and story['epic']['id'] == epic['id']:
                counts = Counter(label['name'] for label in story['labels'])
                origincount.update(counts)
```

I'm having trouble understanding dictionary updates when the values need to be increased together not just "updated".

From the example above when the origincount.update(counts) occurs , it simply changes the value to whatever it is in counts. on the next look it does the same thing.

The problem is I need to increase the value by the counts not just replace it.

I tried looping through counts and doing an if against it being not 0, then adding doing origincount['Bug'] = counts['Bug'] + origincount['Bug']. but that seemed to fail due to my own errors or just not at all.

Update:

```
for epic in epics:
    origin = Counter({
        'Bug': 0,
        'Important': 0,
        'User Story': 0,
        'Critical': 0,
        'Moderate': 0,
        'Low': 0,
        'story': 0
    })

    if epic['archived'] is False:
        for story in stories:
            if story['epic'] is not None and story['epic']['id'] == epic['id']:
                # story_total += 1
                counts = Counter(label['name'] for label in story['labels'])
                print(counts)
                origin = origin + counts

print(origin)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'Bug': 1, 'Important': 1})
Counter({'Critical': 1, 'Bug': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'Bug': 1})
Counter({'Bug': 1, 'Important': 1})
Counter({'Bug': 1, 'Important': 1})
Counter({'Critical': 1, 'Bug': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'Critical': 1, 'Bug': 1})
Counter({'Critical': 1, 'Bug': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'User Story': 1})
Counter({'Critical': 1, 'Bug': 1})
Counter({'Critical': 0, 'User Story': 0, 'Important': 0, 'story': 0, 'Low': 0, 'Bug': 0, 'Moderate': 0})
```

Even with counter conversion of the origin dict it still doesn't add them up.

Comment: You can just add counters together

Comment: so origincount = origincount + counts ?
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'Counter'
the origincount isn't a counter just a dict

Comment: The problem is that `origincount` is NOT a `Counter`. Why don't you make it one?

Comment: Yup just did. totalcount = Counter(origin), and then did a totalcount.update(counts). it's still not updating for some reason.

Comment: @timgeb original post has been updated. included output. still no change.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work, iterate the origincount, for each one check if it's in your othercount, and if it is then update the origincount value.

```
for key, value in origincount.items():
    if key in othercount.keys():
        origincount[key] = value + othercount[key]
```

Comment: I'm moving to the counter() option and it still will not add the values up for some reason.

Comment: sorry I have not used python Counter class before. My solution is for combining counts from 2 separate dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

On every iteration of the loop it appears you are declaring and initializing a new Counter object.

I'd be willing to bet that it gets to end of the loop and then origincounts is just zeroed out on the last iteration.